# Rails form_with to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have a form_with like this:

```
= form_with model: product.product_posts.new do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag :container, '#related-products-list'
  = f.hidden_field :product_id
  = f.hidden_field :post_id, value: @post.id
  = f.submit "+", class: "btn btn-info m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill add-action-button"
```

How to get the same with a link_to to get full div clickable instead of the "+" button?

```
=link_to {SOLUTION} do
    .mydiv
```

Comment: Don't use snippets for non html/js/css code.

Comment: BTW What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Instead to have a "+" submit button I want the same with a link_to do .mydiv to get a full div clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to achieve this. If you use jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mydiv').click(function () {
        $('#form_id').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes but want to do some refacto and look for the rails way

Comment: afaik there's no helper for this. `f.submit` just creates an `<input type="submit">` html tag, which is part of the html specification. The form action is already defined by the `form_with` tag.